# Were all fairies exterminated?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

On episode 19 there are some flashbacks from King which imply that most of them got wiped out. However I'm still a bit unsure...

Is there a fairy realm? Are there any fairies still alive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [wikia](http://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Fairy_Clan) page, some of them are still alive and living in the forest that Ban planted from the seed he was entrusted with by Elaine. There is a fairy realm and it is linked to the human world by the Fairy King's Forest.

> Several year later, fairies begin to inhabit the newly restored Fairy King's Forest after Ban planted the Almoca Seed entrusted by Elaine.